# How can I turn off the photo preview when I plugin in my iPhone on my PC?

Tags: iphone, windows, photos

When I plug in my iPhone 3GS into my Windows XP machine, it automatically opens up Word and displays a preview of all my photos from my phone.

I believe I may have accidentally selected an option to always do that. How do I turn it off?

Comment: Wait, it opens *word*? Do you mean Microsoft Word? That sounds very odd!

Comment: @torbengb It's entirely possible Word would have gotten associated as the default action. You've never had a user email a screenshot pasted into a Word document? I used to get them all the time...

Comment: I see Word-embedded screenshots weekly, but I've never before seen the Scanner-and-Camera thing default to Word.

Answer (score 3):

1. Connect your phone to the computer.
2. In Windows, click Start > Settings > Control Panel > Scanners and Cameras.
3. Right-click on "Apple iPhone" > Properties.
4. Click the tab "Events".
5. Click the radio button "Take no action". Then OK.

Now when you connect the phone, nothing should happen.